# Loop em links de uma pagina com Webbrowser control

Tags: asp.net

boa noite! preciso acessar uma pagina onde ela contem vários links. Preciso entrar em cada um destes links e carregar a proxima pagina para tambem coletar os links da segunda pagina invocada. Eu consegui encontrar os links, mas quando executa o invoker, ele faz apenas para o ultimo link que ele pegou no Loop. o comando que uso é esse:

```
Dim links2 As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames(0).Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")

For Each link2 As HtmlElement In links2
  link2.InvokeMember("Click")
Next
```

Alguem tem uma ideia?

Obrigado

Comment: salvo engano, `HtmlElement` pertence à `System.Windows.Forms`. É asp.net mesmo a tag ?